# Regular expression to match numbers that are not part of words?

Tags: regex

I would like to get a regex where I have the match of a number, but that number doesn't have to be part of the word "720p".
For instance, given the string:

```
A matter of time 78 A 720p
```

I only want the number 78 to be match. What is the expression I need?

Comment: Look at the description of the tag you use. This is easy with some regex engines, and hard with some other ones.

Comment: The answers seem to assume that you want to do something specifically with the "720p" case, but I'm not sure. Do you want to only match numbers that are whole words (no additional characters 'touching' the number)?

Comment: Do you consider `1.0` to be a number in this scenario? How about `1e4`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply

```
\b(\d+)\b
```

That is, only numbers that form a *word*.

Comment: Forgot about the existence of `\b` completely, which is why my answer had the `(\s+|^)`. Upvoted your answer and removed mine.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping to see.  OP is most interested in the word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the numbers that are not part of other words you can use:

```
\b\d+\b
```

\b means "first or last character of a word.

If you explicitly don't want the number if followed by a "p" then you can use:

```
(?>\d+)(?!p)
```

This should match any numbers not followed by the char 'p'.

I recommend using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for building and understanding regular expressions.

Comment: You don't need the capturing group, because `\b` is essentially non-capturing (ie zero width), so the *whole* match is identical to your group 1. Actually this answer is a hair's breadth away from a downvote.